# Spry Tabbed Panels - select menu item without click

Tags: jquery, spry, panels, tabbed

I am using Spry Tabbed Panels. I want to select a menu without clicking. I have set one menu as the default.

When I click on one link or button, the default menu should be activated without a page reload.

How might this be done?

Comment: This is not very clear to me at all. http://adobe.github.com/Spry/samples/tabbedpanels/tabbed_panel_sample.htm You basically want to do what Spry tabs do, but trigger a new page from inside the content area via link or button, instead of the menu?

Comment: For example,i have 3 menu items say :menu1,menu2 and menu3..menu1 is set as default menu..Now,i selec menu3 and there is a button in menu3 contente area.When i click on that button i want default menu (manu1) to be active..

Answer (score 0):

This is in reference to your followup question:

> For example,i have 3 menu items say :menu1,menu2 and menu3..menu1 is set as default menu..Now,i selec menu3 and there is a button in menu3 contente area.When i click on that button i want default menu (manu1) to be active..

Inside your 3rd Tabbed Panel Content, put this `<a href="#" onclick="TabbedPanels1.showPanel(0); return false;">Go to Menu 1</a>`

For clearer understanding, look at the code below:

```
<body>
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Menu 1</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Menu 2</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
<div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 1</div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 2</div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 3 <a href="#" onclick="TabbedPanels1.showPanel(0); return false;">Go to Menu 1</a> </div>
  </div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
</script>
</body>
```

PS. (And to reinforce Joonas's answer) http://adobe.github.com/Spry/samples/tabbedpanels/tabbed_panel_sample.htm

Hope this answers your query!